How to determine if a production function in a functional form has diminishing marginal rate of technical substitution?
For production function $q(L,K) = L^\lambda + K^\gamma$ The MRST is defined as
$\frac{\lambda L^{\lambda-1}}{\gamma K^{\gamma-1}}$. Is it correct and sufficient to say that in order for MRTS to be diminishing: $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ must be between 0 and 1?
If not, what other conditions will this function exhibit diminishing MRTS? Does this function satisfy strong convexity if the parameters are between 0 and 1?

MRST can diminish in two ways: with increasing L or increasing K. For each we need the sign of the partial derivative with respect to the appropriate variable.
For MRST with increasing L we inspect its partial derivative with respect to L:
$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial L} = \frac{\lambda (\lambda-1)L^{\lambda-2}}{\gamma 
 K^{\gamma-1}}$$
We can see that this derivative is negative if, and only if, $0 < \lambda < 1$.
Likewise, the partial derivative of MRST with respect to K is negative if, and only if, $0 < \gamma < 1$.
In addition, the second derivative of MRST with respect to L is positive for $0 < \lambda < 1$.
$$\frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial L^2} = \frac{\lambda (\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)L^{\lambda-3}}{\gamma 
 K^{\gamma-1}}$$
Likewise for $\frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial K^2}$ for $0 < \gamma < 1$.
Together with the negative first derivatives, this implies that MRST is strictly convex.

Couple typos: It's MRTS (not MRST); and it's $\frac{\partial \color{red}K}{\partial L}$ as it measures the slope of the isoquant which lives in the $L$-$K$ plane (similarly for the second-order derivative).

For diminishing MRST, $\lambda < \gamma < 1$. You can say that the function satisfies strong convexity and thus diminishing MRS holds.
